Не работает JPA с Servlet
Только начал разбираться с Java EE. Проблема такова: нет никаого результата после выполения
транзакции JPA, но проблема возникла только тогда, когда я решил это закинуть в сервлет. Возможно неправльно работаю с пакетами javax/jakarta(однако тоже разный варианты пробовал).
Думаю , что проеблема либо в пакетах, либо в настройке jpa. Буду рад ,если объясните.
persistence.xml:
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.2">
<persistence-unit name="UserPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>org.example.jpa.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:test.db"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect">
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>





Пожалуйста не добавляйте код в виде картинок. Используйте разметку markdown

Кстати какой сервер и какой версии используется? Он может просто не поддерживать нужную версию java ee.  Хороший ответ, поясняющий разницу.

Tomcat 10.1.25.

Эта версия поддерживает Jakarta EE 10. Это вроде последняя версия jakarta. Значит пакеты javax,  которые входят в состав java ee   (есть те что входят в состав обычной java) не поддерживает.

Попробуйте заменить javax.persistence на
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>

И начальный тэг в persistence.xml на
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
...

javax и jakarta разные версии java ee.
